# Is it possible to use contenttype with non primary key for the object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I would to use non-primary key in the content type object as the following :

My content type model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object       = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_uid')
    vote         = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

with my other model as :

```
class Task(models.Model):
    uid=uid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=128, help_text=_('Title'))
    votes = GenericRelation(Vote)
```

Now, the schema get create, I am able to create objects, but not to retrieve:
the following doesn't work :

```
t = Task.objects.create(title='task1')
t.votes.all()
```

I get the following error :

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: uuid = integer
LINE 1: ..."content_type_id" = 19 AND "vote"."object_uid" = 16) ORDE...
```

Now I do understand this error, and I understand that its trying to evaluate an integer against an uuid.
Is there a way to indicate django that it should use the `uid` field instead of the `pk` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No, it is not possible to make `GenericForeignKey` use any other target field than the primary key. The primary key is hard-coded in `GenericForeignKey`, `GenericRelation`, and a number of supporting classes (inlines, related descriptors, that kind of thing).

If you really want to use a UUID as the target field, then you'll have to set the UUID field as the primary key on your target model, and use a type compatible with UUIDs as `Vote.object_id` (such as a `CharField`, or even a `TextField` – that way you'll still be able to point to models with an integer primary key, too).

Comment: too bad it is not parameterized yet.

Comment: How would you imagine the API to customize what field is the target of a `GenericForeignKey`? I can come up with two options, both of them ugly: either specify a dict of per-model field name overrides to the `GenericForeignKey` itself, which is icky, because if you wanted to customize the target for several models, you'd end up with a big laundry list in the GFK definition; the other would be to specify it in a `GenericRelation`, which is ugly because then a `GenericRelation` would change the behavior of a GFK defined somewhere else.